# Facebook sharing stopped picking up thumbnail

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, sharing

This was working perfectly this morning now all of a sudden has stopped.
There was some code changes but none that should of effected it.

The meta tags are there for the video and thumbnail.
The entire url I'm sending to share is url encoded

[Link to video](http://player.boomvideo.tv/player.php?id=distro&sv=qne5cnLVmdz6qOuF4RiEQurPfv5FOz8n&ds=Y)

The share url is
`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fplayer.boomvideo.tv%2Ffacebook.php%3Fid%3Dqne5cnLVmdz6qOuF4RiEQurPfv5FOz8n%26fid%3D4AAdR_VnE9f2%26goto%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fbit.ly%252FLMef2j&t=Disney%3A%20Brave%20-%20Warrior%20-%20ROCKYOU%20%7C%20Brought%20to%20you%20by%20www.boomvideo.tv`

All of a sudden this has stopped working. It doesn't seem to pick up any meta tags

Edit: It seems to be extremely temperamental. I ran a debug test and got the following.

**Parser Mismatched Metadata:**

> The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:video:url => http://player.boomvideo.tv/swf/standalone.swf?src=http://wpc.5138.edgecastcdn.net/005138/mps/VID_ID/16/889/05_BOOST_Boxes.mp4, og:video:secure_url => https://player.boomvideo.tv/swf/standalone.swf?src=http://wpc.5138.edgecastcdn.net/005138/mps/VID_ID/16/889/05_BOOST_Boxes.mp4'

Currently using

```
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://player.boomvideo.tv/video.php?pi=distro&mc=300&pw=300&in=300&up=N&ssc=Y&od=N&fta=Y&ap=N&sm=N&fid=4AAdR_VnE9f2&cta=N&sv=9m7REXzzTqzqao3HgGKzJIM83MLqQ5PD&ds=Y" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://wpc.5138.edgecastcdn.net/005138/mps/VID_ID/16/889/05_BOOST_Boxes_200x113_16639846.png" />
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I recommend that you should use Facebook debugger--> https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Edited the question with the results from debug